# How can I get this working (createTable function needs to be called as I click on the submit button)

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a project for my friend I couldn't get it working I need help with the submit button.
I need the submit button to use createTable method onclick. I also couldn't see the variables in the console log. The method is not there yet but I couldn't get other methods working as well simply adding an onclick on the HTML tag does not work.

```js
let profitAfterSponsorship;
let corporateTaxPercentage = 20;
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form');
const cProfit = document.getElementById('cProfit').value;
const sponsoredAmount = document.getElementById('sponsoredAmount').value;
let corporateTax = percentageCalculator(profitAfterSponsorship, corporateTaxPercentage);
let nonSponsoredCorporateTax = percentageCalculator(cProfit, corporateTaxPercentage);
let taxAdvantage = nonSponsoredCorporateTax - corporateTax;

myForm.oninput = () => {
  profitAfterSponsorship = cProfit - sponsoredAmount;
}

function percentageCalculator(amount, percent) {
  return ((percent * amount) / 100).toFixed(2)
}
```

```html
<p><b>Tablo1:<b>Örnek Sponsorluk Vergi Hesaplaması</p>

  <form action="" id="my-form">
    <label for="cProfit">Kurum Kazancı:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="cProfit" name="cProfit"><br>
    <label for="sponsoredAmount">Sponsorluk Miktarı:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="sponsoredAmount" name="sponsoredAmount"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="createTable">
  </form>
```

Comment: It should be `"createTable()"` instead of `"createTable"`. A piece of advice : don't use inline js.

Comment: Thank you for your time man. Doesn't matter how many times I do these I just can't see the simplest problem sometimes. Thanks for the advice also. I don't even like using it like that my friend just wanted everything to be like this. Maybe the instructor wanted it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the possible reasons that's why it's not working.

- The method createTable should be createTable()
- The page is being refreshed every time you click the "Submit"
  button

I've tweaked your code a little bit to make the console.log() work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p><b>Tablo1:<b>Örnek Sponsorluk Vergi Hesaplaması</p>

  <form action="" id="my-form">
    <label for="cProfit">Kurum Kazancı:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="cProfit" name="cProfit"><br>
    <label for="sponsoredAmount">Sponsorluk Miktarı:</label><br>
    <input type="number" id="sponsoredAmount" name="sponsoredAmount"><br><br>
  </form>
  
  <button onclick="createTable()">Submit</button>

  <script>
    let profitAfterSponsorship;
    let corporateTaxPercentage = 20;
    const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form');
    const cProfit = document.getElementById('cProfit').value;
    const sponsoredAmount = document.getElementById('sponsoredAmount').value;
    let corporateTax = percentageCalculator(profitAfterSponsorship, corporateTaxPercentage);
    let nonSponsoredCorporateTax = percentageCalculator(cProfit, corporateTaxPercentage);
    let taxAdvantage = nonSponsoredCorporateTax - corporateTax;

    myForm.oninput = () => {
      profitAfterSponsorship = cProfit - sponsoredAmount;
    }

    function percentageCalculator(amount, percent) {
      return ((percent * amount) / 100).toFixed(2)
    }
    
    function createTable()
    {
        console.log("This is the cProfit:" + cProfit);
        console.log("This is the sponsoredAmount:" + sponsoredAmount);
    }

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

- Moved the "submit" element after the "form" wrapper
- Added a createTable() method

Comment: Thank you so much. May the force be with you

Comment: If it solved your problem, don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the "check button". Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reasons behind your code break are:
createTable method should be createTable()
Variables should be initialized dynamically
I changed some part of your code to work

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p><b>Tablo1:<b>Örnek Sponsorluk Vergi Hesaplaması</p>
      <form action="" id="my-form">
         <label for="cProfit">Kurum Kazancı:</label><br>
         <input type="number" id="cProfit" name="cProfit"><br>
         <label for="sponsoredAmount">Sponsorluk Miktarı:</label><br>
         <input type="number" id="sponsoredAmount" name="sponsoredAmount"><br><br>
      </form>
      <button onclick="createTable()">Submit</button>
      <script>
         let profitAfterSponsorship;
         let corporateTaxPercentage = 20;
         let cProfit;
         let sponsoredAmount;
         const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form');
         
         myForm.oninput = () => {
         cProfit = document.getElementById('cProfit').value;
         sponsoredAmount = document.getElementById('sponsoredAmount').value
         profitAfterSponsorship = cProfit - sponsoredAmount;
         }
         
         function percentageCalculator(amount, percent) {
           return ((percent * amount) / 100).toFixed(2)
         }
         
         function createTable()
         {
         
         let corporateTax = percentageCalculator(profitAfterSponsorship, corporateTaxPercentage);
         let nonSponsoredCorporateTax = percentageCalculator(cProfit, corporateTaxPercentage);
         let taxAdvantage = nonSponsoredCorporateTax - corporateTax;
             console.log("This is the cProfit:" + cProfit);
             console.log("This is the sponsoredAmount:" + sponsoredAmount);
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```